# How to write a series of incoming values to csv in java

Tags: java, arrays, export-to-csv

I have a code which produces 3 values `x,y,z`.
`x,y,z` will be updating every moment.
I need to write these values to csv file in java.
Help me

```
start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String tempX = String.valueOf(lastX);
                String tempY = String.valueOf(lastY);
                String tempZ = String.valueOf(lastZ);
                // System.out.println("x value: " + temp);
                CSVWriter csv = null;
                try {
                    csv = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("/sdcard/myfile.csv"), ',');
                    //List<String> lists = new ArrayList<String>();
                    String[] values = new String[]{tempX,tempY,tempZ,"1"};

                        csv.writeNext(values);

                    csv.close();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Able to write CSV", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to write CSV", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
```

Comment: add the code you already have

Comment: my x,y and z are like updating every now and then so I need to save all those x,y,z values to a csv file

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? What kind of help you want? Your x and y and z values are updated on regular basis and that does not look like problem. Please clearly state what is the problem that you are facing and need help with? Is the code that you added in question not working, if yes, what is the error. If the help is with something else then clearly define what so we help you accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of looping through entries of String[] array and writing it to CSV you can pass the entire array as follow:

```
/* 
 * bellow will insert values array values.length times, 
 */
for(int i=0;i<values.length;i++){
    csv.writeNext(values);
}
```

Replacing above with below, writes all the entries of array to CSV

```
csv.writeNext(values);
```

I have come up with the following solution using the OpenCSV. For testing purpose, I have added a loop to insert values to the CSV to give you an idea how you can update the CSV.

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import com.opencsv.CSVWriter;

public class OpenCSVTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CSVProcessor process = new CSVProcessor(); 

        String[] entries = new String[]{"1","2","3","x"}; 

        //assume each loop is when you get updated entries
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            //store to the file 
            process.storeUpdatedValues(entries);

            //change the vaues to simulate update in x,y,z
            entries[0] = entries[0] + 5; 
            entries[1] = entries[1] + 10; 
            entries[2] = entries[2] + 3; 
            entries[3] = entries[3] + "i:" + i; 
        }
    }
}

class CSVProcessor {
    public void storeUpdatedValues(String[] entries) {
        CSVWriter writer;
        try {
             /*
              *  First arg to CSVWriter is FileWriter that references your file in the disk
              *  Second arg to the CSVWriter is the delimiter, can be comma, tab, etc. 
              *  First arg to FileWriter is location of your file to write to 
              *  Second arg to FileWriter is a flag stating that if file found then append to it 
              */
             writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\test_java\\yourfile.csv", true), ',');

            // feed in your array - you don't need to loop through the items of array
             writer.writeNext(entries);

             // close the writer.
             writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

You get the following output when you run the program once (5 rows because loop is run five times):

```
1          2             3           x
15         210           33          xi:0
155        21010         333         xi:0i:1
1555       2101010       3333        xi:0i:1i:2
15555      210101010     33333       xi:0i:1i:2i:3
```

Steps to use the CSVProcessor class:

1. Instantiate it and create an object
2. Whenever the values of x,y,z are updated then pass them to instance of CSVProcessor
3. Repeat line 2 whenever x,y,z is updated. Your updates will get appended to the CSV.

Comment: Hey I used the suggested one too, but it is writing only one set of array into csv, where as I need the values to be updated for all xyz values.

Comment: I need to run  a loop for writing all the updated xyz to csv. Help me there please

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing? Any errors?

Comment: I am getting only one set of values in csv

Comment: Post other parts of your code too? I cannot see how the values of x,y,z changes to be able to tell why that happens.

Comment: xyz values are coordinate values. So I created a button on mobile so that when I start the button it should write the xyz values onto csv.
Hence xyz will be changing all time.

Comment: Show the code for button and how you get the coordinate values. You have included part of the code in question, hard to understand what happens before the writing to csv is executed.

Comment: I edited the question. Hava a look. 
I am getting those xyz from the accelrometer sensor which changes very fast.

Comment: Ok, now I see the code. I assume that lastX, lastY, and lastZ have valid values. What happens? Do you get any error when the csv.write() is executed? Does the file get created at all in the sd card?

Comment: Yes I get the file created and written too, but only one set of xyz are written.

Comment: try changing  **csv = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("/sdcard/myfile.csv"), ',');**   with    **csv = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("/sdcard/myfile.csv", true), ',');**    I have a strong feeling that the issue is because you open the file new, so every time you write a new file is created rather than appending to the end of the file.

Comment: Nope. Still I have only one row written.

Comment: Delete that file and try again. Also put a log statement inside the onClick() method to find out how many times the method gets called. Let's same, you click a button 4 times and it should call the onClick() method 4 times and it should write to CSV 4 times.

Comment: Yes I am getting now the number of rows depending on number of clicks, but user cannot click that any times, so now I need to start writing the xyz to csv only when I click the button once and then stop writing when I click another button named stop.

Answer (score 0):

Use FileWrite to write x,y,z into a csv file.
Please read this code sample. It is self-explanatory.

```
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;

    private static final String COMMA_DELIMITER = ",";
    private static final String NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR = "\n";
    private static final String FILE_HEADER = "x,y,z";

    FileWriter fileWriter = null;
    try {
        fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName);
        fileWriter.append(FILE_HEADER.toString());
        fileWriter.append(NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR);
        // Write x, y, z
        fileWriter.append(x);
        fileWriter.append(y);
        fileWriter.append(z);
        System.out.println("CSV file was created successfully !!!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error in CsvFileWriter !!!");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            fileWriter.flush();
            fileWriter.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error while flushing/closing fileWriter !!!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/writeread-csv-files-in-java-example/

Comment: I am using CSV Writer to do that.